# How to get Controls in infopath forms programming

Tags: sharepoint, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, infopath

I have do some customizations in the infopath forms , so i have choose edit form the code option when a button clicked...I would like to know how can we get the control ids in the code.please let me know how to start with the programing in infopath.

Comment: what do you mean with "get the control ids"? please explain more

Comment: I mean in the code behind how can we access the controls that are in Infopath Form

Comment: You cannot access the controls directly because they aren't actual objects (like WinForm controls) - they are rendered at runtime via html/javascript. Please provide more info about what you are trying to archieve.

Comment: Andreas i need to do the custom operations in infopath form.For eg: in need to save the values from the infopath form fields to sharepoint list.so i need to get the values from every field, and other one is in the form load i need to get the query string value also...(Query string might be possible using request and respose) but how can we get the values of infopath form fields

Comment: to retrieve a value from a field refer to this article [link](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/retrieve-value-infopath-form-field-code.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Eg:
string fieldValue = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode(
"/my:myFields/my:field1", NamespaceManager).Value;